# Conditional cumulative sum/difference in R

Tags: r, loops, cumulative-sum

I have the following dataset:

```
 library(data.table)
 dt <- fread('
    Year   ID   Total      Quantity
    2017   A     2000        100
    2016   A     2000        200 
    2015   A     2000        50
    2014   B     2000        100
    2013   B     2000        300
 ')
```

I would like to create the following dataset:

```
  want <- fread('
         Year   ID   Total      Quantity   Balance
         2017   A     2000        100       1900
         2016   A     2000        200       1700
         2015   A     2000         50       1650
         2014   B     2000        100       1650
         2013   B     2000        300       1650
   ')
```

The `balance` column is created by subtracting `Quantity` from `Total` only when ID == A. However, this is a cumulative process, where we first calculate balance for the first row (1900), then use that value to calculate the balance in the second row (1900 - 200 = 1700).

Any suggestions for how I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing that out.  I just updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cumsum` of `dt$Quantity` multiplied with the condition `dt$ID=="A"`, assuming that the first row could be used for a start.

```
dt$Balance <- dt$Total[1] - cumsum(dt$Quantity * +(dt$ID=="A"))
dt
#   Year ID Total Quantity Balance
#1: 2017  A  2000      100    1900
#2: 2016  A  2000      200    1700
#3: 2015  A  2000       50    1650
#4: 2014  B  2000      100    1650
#5: 2013  B  2000      300    1650
```